# How to take div height, after the div content is fully loaded

Tags: jquery, css

My page has two divs ..

The left div is a set of links , and the right div is the content container it  has paragraphs and images  ..

The right div has an auto height . And the left div takes the right div's height when the window opened , or when i resize the window  by jquery.

The problem is , the left div takes the right div's height before the right div's content is fully loaded loaded . So  it takes wrong height

Here's an image of the problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Pj9Y.png)

and here's the full code

```js
 $('.left').height($('.right').height());
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
}
.left {
  background: #EEE;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 250px;
}
.right {
  width: 700px;
  margin-left: 250px;
  background-color: darkseagreen;
}
.right img {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="left">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">profile</a>
  <a href="#">about</a>
  <a href="#">ask</a>
  <a href="#">etc</a>
</div>
<div class="right">
  <h4>this is content</h4>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</div>
```

he question is .. How could i take the right div's height after it has been loaded

Comment: Have you tried [$(document).ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)?

Comment: Maybe outerHeight() will work?

Comment: You should try flexbox http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp